# I keep getting error “no module named tkinter” GUI based weighted/average grade calculator program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I keep getting error “no module named tkinter” the code is supposed to create a GUI based weighted/average grade calculator program.The program should receive my raw scores(%) for the various categories of assignments and exams through a GUI. Then calculate weighted average and the corresponding Letter Grade. My program should then display results of weighted average and letter grade.

```
#IMPORT TKINTER MODULE
import tkinter
#CREATION OF CLASS FOR GRADE CALCULATOR
class GradeCalc:
    def __init__(self, win):
#CREATING LABELS FOR EACH SUBJECT
        self.lbl1=Label(win, text='Discussions')
        self.lbl2=Label(win, text='Revel Labs')
        self.lbl3=Label(win, text='Quizzes')
        self.lbl4=Label(win, text='Programs/Project')
        self.lbl5=Label(win, text='Exam1')
        self.lbl6=Label(win, text='Exam2')
        self.lbl7=Label(win, text='Final Exam')
        self.lbl8=Label(win, text='Final Grade')
#CREATING TEXT BOX FOR EACH SUBJECT
        self.t1=Entry(bd=3)
        self.t2=Entry()
        self.t3=Entry()
        self.t4=Entry()
        self.t5=Entry()
        self.t6=Entry()
        self.t7=Entry()
        self.t8=Entry()
#PLACING THE TEXT BOX IN THE CORRECT PLACE
        self.lbl1.place(x=100, y=25)
        self.t1.place(x=200, y=25)
        self.lbl2.place(x=100, y=50)
        self.t2.place(x=200, y=50)
        self.lbl3.place(x=100, y=75)
        self.t3.place(x=200, y=75)
        self.lbl4.place(x=100, y=100)
        self.t4.place(x=200, y=100)
        self.lbl5.place(x=100, y=125)
        self.t5.place(x=200, y=125)
        self.lbl6.place(x=100, y=150)
        self.t6.place(x=200, y=150)
        self.lbl7.place(x=100, y=175)
        self.t7.place(x=200, y=175)
#CALLING THE FUNCTION TO CALCULATE GRADE
        self.b1=Button(win, text='Calculate Grade', command=self.calgrade)
        self.b1.place(x=250, y=210)
        self.lbl8.place(x=100, y=250)
        self.t8.place(x=200, y=250)
        self.b2=Button(win, text='Clear', command=self.clear)
        self.b2.place(x=100, y=210) 
#FUNCTION TO CONVERT THE INPUT FROM STRING TO INTEGER AND CALCULATE GRADES
def calgrade(self):
    self.t8.delete(0, 'end')
    mark1=int(self.t1.get())
    mark2=int(self.t2.get())
    mark3=int(self.t3.get())
    mark4=int(self.t4.get())
    mark5=int(self.t5.get())
    mark6=int(self.t6.get())
    mark7=int(self.t7.get())
    result = ((mark1*5) + (mark2*10) + (mark3*10) + (mark4*15) + (mark5*15) + (mark6*15) + (mark7*30))/7
    if(result >= 89.45 and result<=100):
        res = "A"
    elif(result<89.45 and result>=79.45):
        res = "B"
    elif(result<79.45 and result>=69.45):
        res = "C"
    elif(result<69.45 and result>=59.45):
        res = "D"
    elif(result>100 or result<0):
        root = tkinter()
        root.geometry("200x100")
        msg = Message( root, text = "Check your marks Correctly")
        msg.pack()
        res = "Entered Wrong Marks"
        root.mainloop()
    elif(result<59.45 and result>=0):
        res = "F"
        self.t8.insert(END, str(res))
def clear(self):
    self.t1.delete(0, 'end')
    self.t2.delete(0, 'end')
    self.t3.delete(0, 'end')
    self.t4.delete(0, 'end')
    self.t5.delete(0, 'end')
    self.t6.delete(0, 'end')
    self.t7.delete(0, 'end')
#GLOBAL FUNCTIONS TO DISPLAY THE GRADE CALCULATOR AND EXECUTE ABOVE FUNCTIONS
window=Tk()
mywin=GradeCalc(window)
window.title('Weighted Average/Grade Calculator')
window.geometry("400x300+10+10")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: where are you running this? Pycharm, CLI, Some other IDE?, Linux..some more details please, which `env`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just Edited Your Code And Check My Edits

```
#IMPORT TKINTER MODULE
from tkinter import *
#CREATION OF CLASS FOR GRADE CALCULATOR
class GradeCalc:
    def __init__(self, win):
#CREATING LABELS FOR EACH SUBJECT
        self.lbl1=Label(win, text='Discussions')
        self.lbl2=Label(win, text='Revel Labs')
        self.lbl3=Label(win, text='Quizzes')
        self.lbl4=Label(win, text='Programs/Project')
        self.lbl5=Label(win, text='Exam1')
        self.lbl6=Label(win, text='Exam2')
        self.lbl7=Label(win, text='Final Exam')
        self.lbl8=Label(win, text='Final Grade')
#CREATING TEXT BOX FOR EACH SUBJECT
        self.t1=Entry(bd=3)
        self.t2=Entry()
        self.t3=Entry()
        self.t4=Entry()
        self.t5=Entry()
        self.t6=Entry()
        self.t7=Entry()
        self.t8=Entry()
#PLACING THE TEXT BOX IN THE CORRECT PLACE
        self.lbl1.place(x=100, y=25)
        self.t1.place(x=200, y=25)
        self.lbl2.place(x=100, y=50)
        self.t2.place(x=200, y=50)
        self.lbl3.place(x=100, y=75)
        self.t3.place(x=200, y=75)
        self.lbl4.place(x=100, y=100)
        self.t4.place(x=200, y=100)
        self.lbl5.place(x=100, y=125)
        self.t5.place(x=200, y=125)
        self.lbl6.place(x=100, y=150)
        self.t6.place(x=200, y=150)
        self.lbl7.place(x=100, y=175)
        self.t7.place(x=200, y=175)
#CALLING THE FUNCTION TO CALCULATE GRADE
        self.b1=Button(win, text='Calculate Grade', command=self.calgrade)
        self.b1.place(x=250, y=210)
        self.lbl8.place(x=100, y=250)
        self.t8.place(x=200, y=250)
        self.b2=Button(win, text='Clear', command=self.clear)
        self.b2.place(x=100, y=210) 
#FUNCTION TO CONVERT THE INPUT FROM STRING TO INTEGER AND CALCULATE GRADES
    def calgrade(self):
        self.t8.delete(0, 'end')
        mark1=int(self.t1.get())
        mark2=int(self.t2.get())
        mark3=int(self.t3.get())
        mark4=int(self.t4.get())
        mark5=int(self.t5.get())
        mark6=int(self.t6.get())
        mark7=int(self.t7.get())
        result = ((mark1*5) + (mark2*10) + (mark3*10) + (mark4*15) + (mark5*15) + (mark6*15) + (mark7*30))/7
        if(result >= 89.45 and result<=100):
            res = "A"
        elif(result<89.45 and result>=79.45):
            res = "B"
        elif(result<79.45 and result>=69.45):
            res = "C"
        elif(result<69.45 and result>=59.45):
            res = "D"
        elif(result>100 or result<0):
            root = tkinter()
            root.geometry("200x100")
            msg = Message( root, text = "Check your marks Correctly")
            msg.pack()
            res = "Entered Wrong Marks"
            root.mainloop()
        elif(result<59.45 and result>=0):
            res = "F"
            self.t8.insert(END, str(res))
    def clear(self):
        self.t1.delete(0, 'end')
        self.t2.delete(0, 'end')
        self.t3.delete(0, 'end')
        self.t4.delete(0, 'end')
        self.t5.delete(0, 'end')
        self.t6.delete(0, 'end')
        self.t7.delete(0, 'end')
#GLOBAL FUNCTIONS TO DISPLAY THE GRADE CALCULATOR AND EXECUTE ABOVE FUNCTIONS
window=Tk()
mywin=GradeCalc(window)
window.title('Weighted Average/Grade Calculator')
window.geometry("400x300+10+10")
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statement: `import tkinter`, change it to `from tkinter import *`
. After doing so, indent your `functions` from line 47 to line 82. It should work by then. You keep getting an error because of how you constructed your import statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the tkinter package.

First try to install using the python installer pip:

```
pip install tkinter
```

If this doesn't work, you have to install it using apt:

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

When you import your tkinter module this way:

```
import tkinter
```

you have to declare your variable this way:

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
```

otherwise you have to change your import statement to:

```
from tkinter import Tk
```